# how to make java - tomee application HTTPS?

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, https, apache-tomee

I have been developing a web application with java and apache tomee, but I want to make it https so I can offer it to a few clients but I have no idea on how to create the certificates and make the application go through a secure channel.

I have tried a few tutorials bit I don't seem to have any luck.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial site, and your question isn't really related to code. Maybe research over at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ or even https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `server.xml`:

```
!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="443" 
           maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreType="Windows-MY"
           keyAlias="MyKeyAliasInWindowsKeystore"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Tomee is basically a tomcat with a bunch of J2EE libraries, so the SSL function is actually performed by Tomcat.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: thank you alex440, I am giving it a try as we speak, I'll let you know how it goes.